# Working with Phalcon relations

Tags: php, model, phalcon, relationships

I've started to learn programming with Phalcon a few weeks ago and I have a question about the relationships, which are used for 'easy' programming.

**The setup**
I've got a table full with products (Products model obvious), a table with categories (Category model) and a table with subcategories (Subcategory model). A product CAN be in a category or a subcategory (depends if the category has subcategories).

So, I've currently got 4 models
- Product (matches with **id**)
- Category (matches with **id**)
- Subcategory (matches with **id**)
- CatRelation (used for **linking** the products)

The CatRelation table contains a:
- productId
- satId
- subId

Where the catId/subId cannot be filled both.

So, when I'm in a category, I want to use the model to fetch all the **products** within that category by **catId**. The same goes for the **subcategory**.

My current models look like this:

```
class Product extends ModelBase
{
    public $id;
    public $name;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSource()
    {
        return "products";
    }

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany("id", "CatRelation", "productId");
    }
}

class Category extends ModelBase
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSource()
    {
        return "categories";
    }

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany("id", "CatRelation", "catId");
    }
} 

class Subcategory extends ModelBase
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSource()
    {
        return "subcategories";
    }

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany("id", "CatRelation", "subId");
    }
} 

class CatRelation extends ModelBase
{
    public $id;

    public $productId;
    public $catId;
    public $subId;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSource()
    {
        return "productCatRelations";
    }

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->belongsTo("productId", "Product", "id");
        $this->belongsTo("catId", "Category", "id");
        $this->belongsTo("subId", "Subcategory", "id");
    }
}
```

I hope someone out there is willing to help me out! :)
If you have some suggestions, please suggest them! I'm still learning, so that's only helping me.

Cheers.

Comment: Why does subcategories need its own table? You can accomplish everything you have planned with three tables. Categories, Products, and Categories_to_products. Categories belong to categories, and products have a many to many relationships with categories. What does this not cover in your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never worked with `belongsTo`, but can you try a many-to-many relationship in Category Model.

```
$this->hasManyToMany("id", "CatRelation", "catId",
"productId", "Product", "id",['alias' => 'Product']);
```

Then, if you want to get all the products for each category, try:

```
$rows = Category::query()->execute();

foreach($rows as $row)
{
    var_dump($row->Product->toArray());
}
```